# How to insert char before every digit?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

In a text file i have this:

```
txt txt 12345 12345678
txt 1234
```

i need to insert `;` before every number like this:

```
txt txt;12345;12345678
txt;1234
```

how to do that with `sed`, `awk` or `perl`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems like you actually want to *replace* a whitespace character with `;` only where it is followed by a digit. You could do that in Perl using a *lookahead assertion*:

```
$ cat file
txt txt 12345 12345678
txt 1234

$ perl -pe 's/\s(?=\d)/;/g' file
txt txt;12345;12345678
txt;1234
```

Comment: thanks! this one made my job.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use `sed` back references:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)/;\1/g' <input_file
```

If you want to replace only numbers with *a single space* before them, use this:

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]+)/;\1/g' <input_file
```

And, if you want to replace *any number of (0 or more) spaces* before a number use this:

```
sed -E 's/ *([0-9]+)/;\1/g' <input_file
```

Replace `*` with `+` for *1 or more spaces* preceding a number.

Comment: thanks! 2nd one do the trick.